# how do I sort a list of values that correspond to 'n' into a large table ordered by 'n'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a list of uncertainties that correspond to a particular values of n that i'll call table 1. I would like to add those uncertainties into a comprehensive large table of data, table 2, that is ordered numerically and in ascending order by n. How could I put attach my uncertainty to the correct corresponding value of n?
My first issue is, my table of uncertainties is a table, not a dataframe. I have the separate arrays but not sure how to combine into a dataframe.

```
 table1 = Table([xrow,yrow])
```

xrow denotes the array of the below 'n' in table1 and yrow denotes the corresponding error.

excerpt of table1:

```
 n      error
 1      0.0
 2      0.00496
 3      0.0096
 4      0.00913
 6      0.00555
 8      0.00718
 10     0.00707
```

excerpt of table2:

```
    n   Energy      g   J   error
0   1   0.000000    1   0     NaN
1   2   1827.486200 1   0   NaN
2   3   3626.681500 1   0   NaN
3   4   5396.686500 1   0   NaN 
4   5   6250.149500 1   0   NaN
```

so the end result should look like this:

```
    n   Energy      g   J     error
0   1   0.000000    1   0     0
1   2   1827.486200 1   0     0.00496
2   3   3626.681500 1   0     0.0096
3   4   5396.686500 1   0     0.00913
4   5   6250.149500 1   0     NaN
```

i.e. the ones where there is no data remains to be blank (e.g. n=5 in the above case)

I should note there is a lot of data (roughly 30k) in table 2 and 2.5k in table1.

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters and format your text. It is unreadable.

Comment: yeah just changed it apologies

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

table1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
 n      error
 1      0.0
 2      0.00496
 3      0.0096
 4      0.00913
 6      0.00555
 8      0.00718
 10     0.00707"""), sep=r"\s+")

table2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
    n   Energy      g   J   error
0   1   0.000000    1   0     NaN
1   2   1827.486200 1   0   NaN
2   3   3626.681500 1   0   NaN
3   4   5396.686500 1   0   NaN 
4   5   6250.149500 1   0   NaN"""), sep=r"\s+")

table2["error"] = table1.merge(table2, on="n", how="right")["error_x"]

print(table2)
```

Output:

```
   n     Energy  g  J    error
0  1     0.0000  1  0  0.00000
1  2  1827.4862  1  0  0.00496
2  3  3626.6815  1  0  0.00960
3  4  5396.6865  1  0  0.00913
4  5  6250.1495  1  0      NaN
```

**EDIT:** using [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) should perform better (see comments):

```py
table2["error"] = table2["n"].map(table1.set_index('n')['error'])
```

Comment: Map should be better/faster here, check dupe.

Comment: @jezrael cool, because instead of joining on possibly non relevant values it just goes index by index of relevant values and sets them only in the desired colmn?

Comment: @jezrael I learn a lot from your answers/comments, thanks for investing the time :) pandas has so many ways to do everything, and some of them may look similar in code but perform very differently.

Comment: yes, exactly, because if need maping by one column only `map` is best here. But if need mapping by multuiple columns, need merge.

Comment: ya, be free add mapping solution too.

Comment: I tried the map method, but it outputs an error saying: AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: Much appreciated btw guys

Comment: @AkhilDewan Sorry, I missed the part where you have a Table and not a DataFrame. where is this Table from? another library?

Comment: @AkhilDewan you should be able to convert xrows and yrows to DataFrame by using `from_dict` like this: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"n":xrow, "error",yrow})`

Comment: Never mind! I managed to convert table1 to a dataframe and the .map worked like a dream!